# DAG not running hourly

Tags: python, airflow

I am new to airflow and trying to run a simple DAG at an hourly rate. `schedule_interval='@hourly'` is not working. My expectation was it will trigger DAG from my `start_date` (Oct 7, 2022 2AM) to NOW every hour since catchup is by default set to True. However, it triggers z DAG once and then stops. Also, on the UI, the Schedule says 1 **day**, not **hour**. The code is given below and the screenshot of UI is also attached. Airflow version is 2.4.1

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator

from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=4),
    'schedule_interval': '@hourly'
}

with DAG(
    dag_id='dag_with_cron_v6',
    description='dag with cron expression',
    start_date=datetime(2022, 10, 7, 2),
    default_args=default_args
) as dag:
    task1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='task_1',
        bash_command='echo Please walk carefully. Slippery floor.'
    )

    task1
```

[Daily Schedule in UI but @hourly in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCVYw.png)

Comment: That's puzzling, your code looks good. Are you sure you've deployed your code? Have you refreshed the DAG? Perhaps you can inspect the code within Airflow, maybe the DAG didn't update?

Comment: I did inspect and it is updating in the Code section of UI

Answer (score 1):

In airflow 2.4.1 **schedule_interval** is deprecated.

You should use the **schedule** argument instead

for more details, look at the [Release Notes](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/release_notes.html#deprecation-of-schedule-interval-and-timetable-arguments-25410)